# why the getline method not give me a chance to enter a message in c++?

Tags: c++, string

The code sample is from http://www.lmpt.univ-tours.fr/~volkov/C++.pdf. Some of you may think string in C++ is better than cstring. You may consider this as a pedagogical purpose.

```
// C-string.cpp : Using C strings.
// -----------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char header[] = "\n *** C Strings ***\n\n";  // define a c string 
int main()
{
  char hello[30] = "Hello ", name[20], message[80];  // define a c string hello, declare two other c strings name and message


  cout << header << "Your first name: ";
  cin >> setw(20) >> name;      // Enter a word.


  strcat( hello, name);      // Append the name.
  cout << hello << endl;
  cin.sync();                // No previous input. 
  cout << "\nWhat is the message for today?"
       << endl;

  cin.getline( message, 80); // Enter a line with a max of 79 characters.
  if( strlen( message) > 0)  // If string length is longer than 0.
    {

      for( int i=0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i)
          cout << message[i] << ' ';
      cout << endl;

   }

return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, the following is the output:

```
 *** C Strings ***
$:~ ./a.out
Your first name: dfdfd
Hello dfdfd

What is the message for today?
$:~
```

On the other hand, if I make a small change to comment some lines as the following:

```
// C-string.cpp : Using C strings.
// -----------------------------------------------------
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char header[] = "\n *** C Strings ***\n\n";  // define a c string 
int main()
{
  char hello[30] = "Hello ", name[20], message[80];  // define a c string hello, declare two other c strings name and message

  /*
  cout << header << "Your first name: ";
  cin >> setw(20) >> name;      // Enter a word.


  strcat( hello, name);      // Append the name.
  cout << hello << endl;
  cin.sync();                // No previous input.
  */ 
  cout << "\nWhat is the message for today?"
       << endl;

  cin.getline( message, 80); // Enter a line with a max of 79 characters.
  if( strlen( message) > 0)  // If string length is longer than 0.
    {

      for( int i=0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i)
          cout << message[i] << ' ';
      cout << endl;

   }

return 0;
```

The output is:

```
What is the message for today?
fdjfdlfjl
f d j f d l f j l
```

My question: why?

**EDIT**: I hope it is not considered as a duplicate, as there is the other related question I asked earlier. [Using std::getline() to read a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649067/using-stdgetline-to-read-a-single-line)

Comment: You need to clear your cin buffer before getline.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18725522/getline-keeps-on-getting-newline-character-how-can-i-avoid-this

Comment: [Why does std::getline() skip input after a formatted extraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)

Comment: @problematicDude, I thought cin.sync() would already clear the cin buffer, does not it?

Comment: You might want to [read more about `sync`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sync) and what it does. Most importantly it does not clear the input buffer in any way.

Comment: @kkxx No, that's not what [`std::istream::sync`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sync) does.

Comment: @kkxx no it won't use ingore to do so.